# stop playing audio player when go back to previous page by Navigator.pop flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to Flutter ... 
i have an **audio file** which is `nameAudio = 'daily_dua.mp3'` in a page, and i want it to stop plying when go back to previous page by `Navigator.pop` ...

i tried, in my **page**

`GlobalKey<AudioPlayClassState> _keyChild1 = GlobalKey();`

and here i call it in `build function`

```
RaisedButton(
              child: Text("stopAudio"),
              onPressed: () {
                _keyChild1.currentState.stopAudio();
              },
```

**error**

```
The method 'stopAudio' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: stopAudio()
```

**why it call null ? and how i could fix it?**

**my code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'AudioPlayClass.dart';

class DailyDuaPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DailyDuaPage createState() => _DailyDuaPage();
}

class _DailyDuaPage extends State<DailyDuaPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  GlobalKey<AudioPlayClassState> _keyChild1 = GlobalKey();

  String nameAudio;

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      nameAudio = 'daily_dua.mp3';
    });
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
//        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          leading: new IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 40,
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: Text(
            "الأوراد الشريفه",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new Image.asset(
                  'assets/daily-dua.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: AudioPlayClass(titleFile: nameAudio),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("stopAudio"),
              onPressed: () {
                _keyChild1.currentState.stopAudio();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AudioPlay Class**

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AudioPlayClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final String titleFile;

  const AudioPlayClass({Key key, this.titleFile}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AudioPlayClassState createState() => AudioPlayClassState();
}

class AudioPlayClassState extends State<AudioPlayClass> {
  Duration duration = new Duration();
  Duration position = new Duration();
  AudioPlayer advancedPlayer;
  AudioCache audioCache;

  bool isPlaying = true;
  bool firstTimePlay = true;

  String stringmintues;
  int getSecond;
  String stringseconds;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlayer();
  }

  void initPlayer() {
    advancedPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer);

    advancedPlayer.durationHandler = (d) => setState(() {
          duration = d;
        });

    advancedPlayer.positionHandler = (p) => setState(() {
          position = p;
        });
  }

  Widget btn() {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: 30,
      height: 50,
      child: RaisedButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
        child: Icon(
          getIcon(),
          size: 40,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        color: Colors.pink[900],
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            print(widget.titleFile);
            if (firstTimePlay == true) {
              audioCache.play('${widget.titleFile}');

              firstTimePlay = false;
            } else {
              isPlaying ? advancedPlayer.pause() : advancedPlayer.resume();
              isPlaying ? isPlaying = false : isPlaying = true;
            }
          });
        },
        onLongPress: () {
          setState(() {
            advancedPlayer.stop();
            isPlaying = false;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  IconData getIcon() {
    if (firstTimePlay == true) {
      return Icons.play_arrow;
    } else {
      IconData oneOfThem;
      isPlaying ? oneOfThem = Icons.stop : oneOfThem = Icons.play_arrow;
      return oneOfThem;
    }
  }

  Widget slider() {
    return Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
      ),
      child: Slider(
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          inactiveColor: Colors.white,
          value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
          min: 0.0,
          max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
          onChanged: (double value) {
            setState(() {
              Duration newDuration = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
              advancedPlayer.seek(newDuration);
              value = value;
            });
          }),
    );
  }

  void positionTimeText() {
    if (position.inMinutes < 10) {
      stringmintues = "0${position.inMinutes}";
    } else {
      stringmintues = "${position.inMinutes}";
    }
    getSecond = position.inSeconds;
    if (getSecond >= 60) {
      getSecond = position.inSeconds % 60;
    }

    if (getSecond < 10) {
      stringseconds = "0$getSecond";
    } else if (getSecond > 9 && getSecond < 60) {
      stringseconds = "$getSecond";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      positionTimeText();
    });
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          btn(),
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, left: 8),
            child: slider(),
          )),
          Container(width: 50, child: Text("$stringmintues : $stringseconds")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void stopAudio() {
    setState(() {
      advancedPlayer.stop();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: AudioPlay class is child one or parent one?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman AudioPlay class  is nother one of them ... it is class call it in child page for audio class

Comment: @MuhammadNoman please take a look again to my question i edited.

Comment: AudioPlay and Audio are two different classes?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman audio file is `nameAudio = 'daily_dua.mp3'` mp3 file.

Comment: Do you want to stop on this? ``onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),``

Comment: @MuhammadNoman yes sir!

Comment: Check the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a mistake here, you have to pass that `GlobalKey` to your Child Class too like this:

```
Container(
    child: AudioPlayClass(key: _keyChild1, titleFile: nameAudio),
),
```

Now this will work easily:

```
onPressed: () {
  _keyChild1.currentState.stopAudio();
},
```